# jira api bad request

Tags: c#, post, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to connect jira with an api. I already got issues, but now I'm trying to create an issue, but it doesn't work. I got the error: Badrequest. So I tried a lot of things, even post nothing, but it doesn't work. It still give the same error.

So is there something in the settings, that is blocking my posts?

Code:

```
    var webAddr = "https://<username>.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/";
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";            

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = "{}";

        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: something doesn't work. mayby you'll post some code then we can try to solve you'r problem, now the only thing we can do it waiting for more details from you

Comment: I've added the code.

Comment: What i see at first look is that you'r not setting Content length header at all. Also I never used jira api so i don't know is it true or not, but in my mind creating issue should be done with some type of authentication. quick google about api led me to this https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-version-2-tutorial which tells me that i'm correct that to do some actions you need to authenticate yourself.

Comment: I did, but i didn't show the code. The authentication works, because I can read the issues, but don't write.

Comment: Can you show an example of the body (json) and the http headers you send to JIRA and the complete response you receive? Bad Request typically has a more detailed error message in its response. Also: why do you think posting an empty body would result in a succesful call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: I used single-quotes instead of dubble quotes in the json string.